# ASP.NET MVC 5 (Framework 4.5.2) BundleConfig Jquery JqGrid Cant Find Images

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, bundle

***SOLVED*** : I do not believe the problem was this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1148674.aspx?can+t+seem+to+load+images+with+iis7

My application can not find the Jquery images. I've tried everything, including various solutions found in the web, nothing worked. All Scripts and styles work perfectly well, only the images are in trouble (do not appear). If anyone knows the solution, please do not refer to any link, but put the answer here. It will be easier for me to understand (my english is not so good).

ps: **Debugging works properly only when I Deploy in IIS is the problem**

### Below I list the codes of the application:

### BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace SysWring.UI.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js",
                     // "~/Scripts/jquery.smartWizard-2.0.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.steps.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/grid.locale-pt-br.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/ui.jqgrid.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.steps.css"));

            // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
            // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

### _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("SysWring", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configuração de Produtos", "Index", "ProdutoBase")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - SysWring ERP</p>
        </footer>

    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

### jquery-ui.css

```
....

/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Gill Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
    font-family: Gill Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background: #ffffff url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #2c4359;
}
.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #2c4359;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #2c4359;
    background: #35414f url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_dots-small_35_35414f_2x2.png") 50% 50% repeat;
    color: #e1e463;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-widget-header a {
    color: #e1e463;
}

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #93c3cd;
    background: #93c3cd url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_50_93c3cd_40x40.png") 50% 50% repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-state-default a,
.ui-state-default a:link,
.ui-state-default a:visited {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: #ccd232 url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_75_ccd232_40x40.png") 50% 50% repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #212121;
}
.ui-state-hover a,
.ui-state-hover a:hover,
.ui-state-hover a:link,
.ui-state-hover a:visited,
.ui-state-focus a,
.ui-state-focus a:hover,
.ui-state-focus a:link,
.ui-state-focus a:visited {
    color: #212121;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #ff6b7f;
    background: #db4865 url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_40_db4865_40x40.png") 50% 50% repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #b4d100;
    background: #ffff38 url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_dots-medium_80_ffff38_4x4.png") 50% 50% repeat;
    color: #363636;
}
.ui-state-highlight a,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a {
    color: #363636;
}
.ui-state-error,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff6b7f;
    background: #ff3853 url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_50_ff3853_40x40.png") 50% 50% repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-error a,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-error-text,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-priority-primary,
.ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary,
.ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-priority-secondary,
.ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary,
.ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary {
    opacity: .7;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=70);
    font-weight: normal;
}
.ui-state-disabled,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: .35;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=35);
    background-image: none;
}
.ui-state-disabled .ui-icon {
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=35); /* For IE8 - See #6059 */
}

/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_c02669_256x240.png");
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_e1e463_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_88a206_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon,
.ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_ffeb33_256x240.png");
}


....
```

### My App

[image: My Application]

Comment: in css file their url is not correct thats the reason

Comment: url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") -> All Images are referenced this way the css file. What should be the correct way? (I've tried to change it and also did not work)

Comment: I imagined that the minimization process (BundleConfig) would hit these paths as needed; Am I wrong?

Comment: I tried everything, it's driving me crazy; Please someone?

Comment: which css file images are not loading?

Comment: all the css files are loaded, though the images are not found. The layout is correct, the colors too, only the images are not found. In specific jqueryui images.

Comment: in jqueryui.css images url is wrong that's why they are not loading replace all url in jqueryui.css which are :``url("/Content/themes/base/images/")`` with ``url("images/")`` as images folder is in root directory where css file are present

Comment: You also did not work…. the same behavior occurs. really, they were like (“images/….“), I moved (“/Content…”) because i saw that answer on another question and marked as were correct.

Comment: press ``ctrl+f5`` to cache refresh your page and then check

Comment: unfortunately, did not work

Comment: I do not believe the problem was this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1148674.aspx?can+t+seem+to+load+images+with+iis7

Comment: @PauloAmf , I believe that css is looking for images relative to where the css file is , and after it is minified look to see what folder your minified css is in

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform CssRewriteUrlTransform() on each css file, so that the resources they reference via a relative path are rewritten as absolute paths.
MSDN: [CssRewriteUrlTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, do not include all.css nor base.css in the bundle. Their use of '@Import' will generate a minification error, and they are redundant.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqueryUI/themes/base/css")
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/button.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/core.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/draggable.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/menu.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/selectMenu.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/slider.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/sortable.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())        
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/spinner.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/theme.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
       .Include("~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
       .Include("~/Scripts/qTip/jquery.qtip.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
 );
```